# React Native WebView onMessage call stops the WebView from executing onLoadEnd

Tags: android, react-native, webview, wkwebview, expo

Here's a simple WebView I am trying to test this with. The following code returns the following in the console:

```
Handle Load Start
Handle Load
Handle Load End
Handle Load Start
{"listening":"Sup"}
```

```
export default class SimpleWebview extends React.Component {
  handleOnLoadStart = e => {
    console.log(`Handle Load Start`)
  }

  handleOnLoad = e => {
    console.log(`Handle Load`)
  }

  handleOnLoadEnd = e => {
    console.log(`Handle Load End`)
  }

  handleError = e => {
    console.log(`Handle Error`)
  }

  handleMessage = e => {
    const { data } = e.nativeEvent
    console.log(data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={styles.webviewWrapper}
          ref={webviewRef => {
            this.webviewRef = webviewRef
          }}
        >
          <WebView
            ref={webView => {
              this.webView = webView
            }}
            source={{ html: '<h1>Simple webview</h1>' }}
            javaScriptEnabled
            injectedJavaScript={`window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ listening: 'Sup' }), '*')`}
            onLoad={this.handleOnLoad}
            onLoadEnd={this.handleOnLoadEnd}
            onLoadStart={this.handleOnLoadStart}
            onMessage={this.handleMessage}
            startInLoadingState
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}
```

From my understanding, `injectedJavascript` gets executed after the webview has finished loading, however, I am not sure why it invokes the `onLoadStart` method. Wouldn't that introduce an infinite loop?

I am trying to set up a connection between the webview and the app, where I can call methods at different times and it would execute certain functions within the webview.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Only one of `Onload`, `OnloadStart`, or `OnloadEnd`.

It doesn't matter if you have to use it all.

Please refer to the [manual](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/react-native/webview/) for components.

`onMessage` is used when webview messages to the web.

examplewebview.js:

```js
onLoadEnd() {
    const user = this.state.messageusername;
    const data = { messageType: "webview", user }; 
    this.webview.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data));

  }
```

webListener:

```html
window.onload = function() {
            document.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

              let tes = JSON.parse(e.data);

          alert(tes.data);

});
}
```